Setting default value on a Missing column when giving a schema during CreateDataframe on Spark
I have a dataset with the following format:
data = [{"Name":"John", "Family": "Doe}, {"Name":"Jack"}]

And the following schema:
schema = StructType([StructField("Name", StringType(), False),
                     StructField("Family", StringType(), True)])

Is there any way to create a default value during the Dataframe creation giving a schema?
df = spark_session.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=schema)

Let's say I want to obtain something like this



Name
Family




John
Doe


Jack
null



Thank you in advance

Spark doesn't support default column value while creating schema.

Your code creates exactly the dataframe that you have given with a null value in the second row.

If you're referring to a DEFAULT constraint, which automatically assigns a default value when no value is provided, Spark does not support this in the schema when creating a DataFrame. Spark itself doesn't support basic constraints like PRIMARY KEY. However, Databricks SQL (based on Spark) does offer some constraint features. This highlights that Spark is primarily focused on data processing, not data basing.
However, you can use fillna(), coalesce() or when() functions to replace NULLs with other values. For example:
df.na.fill({'family': 'default_family'})
# or 
df.select(
  when(df.family.isNull(),'default_family')
  .otherwise(df.family).alias('family'), df.name)

Physical plan shows that fillna() actually works like coalesce() (not to be confused with the one used for partitioning). Both return the first non-null value from the given columns (see the lit() column created from the default value). The example below should help clarify this.
>>> df.na.fill({'family': 'default_family'}).explain()
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [coalesce(family#238, default_family) AS family#394, name#239]
+- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[family#238,name#239]

>>> df.select(coalesce(df.family, lit('default_family')).alias('family'), df.name).explain()
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [coalesce(family#238, default_family) AS family#395, name#239]
+- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[family#238,name#239]

Also, you can consider options like nullValue when reading CSV files.
